# Multiple Actions with One button

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I have two windows in MainMenu.xib

Is it possible to close both windows from one action button which is on second window.??

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Binding you can close either one, by Ctrl+Drag to the window and select `performClose:`

Using Code you can do as:

Create an IBAction and use :

```
- (IBAction)closeAll:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"closing both windows");

    [self.secondaryWindow close];
    [self.window close];//for primary

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure.

Create one new IBAction and assign it as a target to your button.

Then in that IBAction, close both windows (which is possible if you have pointers or IBOutlets to those "`NSWindow`" objects).